# PHP Unit Testing -- Is this overly mocked? -- Public method loops/calls other public method

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-query-builder

FUNCTIONALITY

I have a Laravel project in which I have extended `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` as an `AbstractSearch` class to introduce a `params()` method that calls the abstract method `applyParams()` to be defined when `AbstractSearch` is extended.

Example:

```
$models = (new ModelSearch)
    ->params(['name' => 'Model', 'createdBefore' => now()])
    ->with(['modelCategory', 'modelType'])
    ->paginate();
```

`applyParams()` is responsible for taking the array parameter from `params()` and properly constructing the underlying `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` query.

The `AbstractSearch` class allows casting of these parameters via a protected `$casts` attribute and a `castParams(array $params = [])` method.

`castParams()` loops through the protected `$casts` attribute and calls `$this->castParam($params, $field, $cast)` for each element.

Right now, both `castParams()` and `castParam()` are public methods, even though the likelihood of `castParam()` ever being called that way is practically zero.

Relevent excerpt from `AbstractSearch`:

```
public function params(array $params = [])
{
    return $this->applyParams(
        $this->prepareParams($params)
    );
}

abstract function applyParams(array $params = []);

public function prepareParams(array $params = []) : array
{
    return $this->castParams(
        $this->applyDefaults($params)
    );
}

public function applyDefaults(array $params = []) : array
{
    foreach ($this->defaults as $field => $value) {
        data_fill($params, $field, $value);
    }

    return $params;
}

public function getCasts()
{
    return $this->casts;
}

public function castParams(array $params = []) : array
{
    foreach ($this->getCasts() as $field => $cast) {
        $this->castParam($params, $field, $cast);
    }

    return $params;
}

public function castParam(&$params, $field, $cast)
{
    if (! isset($params[$field])) {
        return;
    }

    switch ($cast) {
        case 'date':
        case 'datetime':
            if (! $params[$field] instanceof Carbon) {
                $params[$field] = Carbon::parse($params[$field]);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

TESTING

I have unit tests in place for both methods. The bulk of the testing is done on `castParam()` to ensure that casting is done properly.

The unit test for `castParams()` is done with a partial mock of the `AbstractSearch` class that expects various calls to `castParam()`.

QUESTIONS

I recently re-read some unit testing principles that made me question this class's setup. You can see from the excerpt above that there are a lot of public methods that should probably be protected. In fact, the only method that *needs* to be public is `params()`.

It logically follows that `params()` should be the only public method; however, `params()` relies on the abstract method `applyParams()` so any test of `params()` would have to be done on the extending class because the results rely on what `applyParams()` does.

So...

1. Have I talked myself to the right spot with the above two paragraphs? It sounds right to me, but it would involve testing that `params()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and that the expected changes were made to the Builder's underlying `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and its query. I'm not entirely sure that's even possible.
2. Going back to `castParams()` and the partial mock's expectations that it will call `castParam()` several times. If both `castParams()` and `castParam()` remain public methods *and* if testing should focus on observable behavior, won't I have redundant tests if I test both? Or is it generally acceptable to mock the `castParam()` calls in my `castParams()` test since `castParam()` will be thoroughly tested? (EDIT: This question also applies generally to any public method that calls other public methods.)

Comment: CURRENTLY THINKING: make all methods except `params()` protected, scrap the pure-code unit tests, and use database-dependent integration tests to test resulting query against actual database.